# How can I transmit MQTT messages in scheduled background threads?

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I was successfully running MQTT based application.

Over time I've migrated w.r.t. SW component versions and I moved MQTT message transmissions into [APScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) background threads. The client instance is passed to job scheduling via dependency injection.

Now I'm using mosquitto eclipse mqtt broker docker image `eclipse-mosquitto:1.6.10` and Python paho client `paho-mqtt = "1.5.0"`.

Now if I try to connect with a client to the broker the connection gets diconnected and I get the error `Connection Refused: unacceptable protocol version.` which is thrown [in the v1.5 client source code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/v1.5.0/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L226).

The client connects as follows:

```
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name,unused-argument
    print(mqtt.connack_string(rc))

client = mqtt.Client(
    client_id="mvp-end-device-agent",
    clean_session=False,
    protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311,
)
client.on_disconnect = on_disconnect
user = "mvp-end-device-agent"
pwd = "some-string"
client.username_pw_set(user, pwd)
client.connect(host, port)  # implicit timeout of 60 seconds

    def on_disconnect(client, userdata, rc):  # pylint: disable=invalid-name,unused-argument
```

The `mosquitto/config/acl` should still be matching:

```
user mvp-end-device-agent
topic write ...
```

As well as the `mosquitto/config/passwd` config:

```
mvp-end-device-agent:<HASHEDPWD>
```

And the `mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf` config:

```
password_file /mosquitto/config/passwd
acl_file /mosquitto/config/acls
```

The most probable, relevant log entries (`mqtt-explorer-31e2d891` is for debugging, `mvp-end-device-agent` is the actual client):

```
1603891749: New connection from 172.18.0.6 on port 1883.
1603891749: New client connected from 172.18.0.6 as mvp-end-device-agent (p2, c0, k1, u'mvp-end-device-agent').
1603891749: No will message specified.
1603891749: Sending CONNACK to mvp-end-device-agent (1, 0)
1603891750: Received PINGREQ from mqtt-explorer-31e2d891
1603891750: Sending PINGRESP to mqtt-explorer-31e2d891
1603891751: Received PINGREQ from mvp-end-device-agent
1603891751: Sending PINGRESP to mvp-end-device-agent
1603891752: Received PINGREQ from mvp-end-device-agent
1603891752: Sending PINGRESP to mvp-end-device-agent
1603891753: Received PINGREQ from mvp-end-device-agent
1603891753: Sending PINGRESP to mvp-end-device-agent
1603891754: Received PINGREQ from mvp-end-device-agent
1603891754: Sending PINGRESP to mvp-end-device-agent
1603891755: Received PINGREQ from mvp-end-device-agent
1603891755: Sending PINGRESP to mvp-end-device-agent
1603891755: Received DISCONNECT from mvp-end-device-agent
1603891755: Client mvp-end-device-agent disconnected.
```

I have a hard time figuring out the root cause of this issue. What are the potential reasons why this error is thrown?

**EDIT**: I passed the mqtt client via dependency injection to the APScheduler job for scheduled transmission of a MQTT message as part of the job execution. Each job is executed in a thread. It turned out the root cause for `Connection Refused: unacceptable protocol version.` was that after the execution of the thread the client is disconnected implicitly which makes total sense.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `protocol=mqtt.MQTTv311,` from the client constructor?

Comment: Does not make a difference.

Comment: Then turn on mosquito's verbose log output and look what protocol version the client is asking for.

Comment: I've added the probably most relevant log output to the question.

Comment: That log shows a clean disconnect triggered by the client, not a failure to connect caused by a protocol version error.

Comment: I refactored the code to support sending mqtt messages in background jobs using APScheduler. I'll check if I've some wanted disconnects located not properly. Otherweise seems like this is an integration issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223758/discussion-between-thinwybk-and-hardillb).